# How do you call this typical file name order?

Tags: terminology, sorting, strings

```
log1.gz
log10.gz
log100.gz
log101.gz
log102.gz
log103.gz
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: The Q&A sites exist to explain how you failed with your homework, which nobody can benefit from. The chat exists for questions which have the eternal value. I know. But, I will do as I see right.

Comment: 1) No. 2) No. 3) Good luck.

Comment: Off-topic :)) Everybody can open their eyes and see that lexicographic order is defined as `Given two partially ordered sets A and B, the lexicographical order on the Cartesian product A × B is defined as (a,b) ≤ (a′,b′) if and only if a < a′ or (a = a′ and b ≤ b′). ` It certainly should be the concept from the field of social sciences, the history, probably :)). Computer scientists never deal with The sorting, extensions, Cartesian products nor dictionaries and computational lingustics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in the comment, it is called **lexicographic order** in ascending direction; description can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6810681/1205135).